# How to push from UIImagePicker to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble popping to a view controller from an image picker once the user has finished picking an image. Basically I have a user take a photo, then pop the view controller to a new view controller which is in a variegation controller. Here is my code right now, which does not work. I also do not want to go back to the view controller I opened the picker from, because I want to go to an editing area (separate view).

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        // ...
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sendPost")
        picker.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
    })
}
```

Please feel free to give tips, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This will dismiss the `imagePickerController` and take you back to the controller that you opened the `imagePickerController` from.

**Update:**
So start by creating a segue from the viewController that contains the `imagePicker` to the new viewController that you want to pass the image to when the user has finished selecting the image.

After that you just call the segue. The segue identifier is now `ShowNewVC` name that to a appropriate name and in the `prepare` function you just get the destination viewController and pass the image, so you need to declare an image variable that you can set.

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowNewVC", sender: selectedImage)
    }
})

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowNewVC" {
        if let image = sender as? UIImage {
            let newVC = segue.destination as! NewViewController
            newVC.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I open the picker from the root view controller, so I need to then go to an area where users can chose who they want to send the media to, meaning I need to pop view controllers, not just dismiss, thanks though

Comment: So when a user has selected a photo, then you want to go to a new viewController and use the selected image?

Comment: Why not just create a segue to that viewController and in your completion block call that segue and pass the image? Want me to write an example for that?

Comment: How do I create the segue because I am getting the error view controller has no segue with identifier: "ShowNewVC".

Comment: You control drag from the first viewController to your second and then click on the blue line that appears and add an id to it. Got it?

Comment: I actually mean that after creating the segue, it still does not segue for some reason, I connect the view controller to the sendPost view controller and made it a show segue with the identifier of ShowNewVC, but still am getting no action after I click user photo

Comment: Do you have the possibility to zip the project and add it to Dropbox/Google Drive and I´ll have a look at it for you.

Comment: sure hold on one second

Comment: wait nope I got it, I declared it not in the dismiss, thanks man, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Np glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't `pop` to a new view controller. Use `present`:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        // ...
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sendPost")
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: I already have used this method and it looks awkward, so I believe I do not want to dismiss the picker now, only present a  new view

Comment: Set both `animated: false` if you feel the transition is awkward.

Comment: I can't tell if that was meant to be sarcasm, or if it did work.

Comment: no it wasn't sarcasm, but it still looks kinda odd, but Ill wait and see because technically this works, but its not perfect